# Xpages & DataTables

Tags: datatables, xpages

I'm using the dataTables jQuery plugin with xpages and have a custom control I drop onto any page, pass in a custom property of viewName and it will  display a table using REST - All based on some great examples by Oliver Busse.

Everything works perfectly if this custom control is used on a basic page, however, if it is within a tab, which is not default, when I then click on the tab containing the control, I receive an error when calling `viewjson.getId()`

I think the issue is because I set viewjson on beforePageLoad?

Any idea how I can get this to work in a tabbed interface?

Code below:

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var viewjson = new org.openntf.rest.DynamicView(compositeData.viewName);}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <table
        id="#{javascript:viewjson.getId()}"
        class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" disableOutputTag="true"
                var="col">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
viewjson.getCols()}
catch (e) {
openLogBean.addError(e,this)
}}]]></xp:this.value>
                <th>
                    <xp:text escape="true" disableTheme="true"
                        value="#{col}">
                    </xp:text>
                </th>
            </xp:repeat>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

UPDATE

I've tried the following to try and load jQuery first

```
<xp:this.resources>
<xp:headTag
            tagName="script">
            <xp:this.attributes>
                <xp:parameter
                    name="type"
                    value="text/javascript" />
                <xp:parameter
                    name="src"
                    value="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/jquery/jquery.min.js" />
            </xp:this.attributes>
        </xp:headTag>
        </xp:this.resources>
```

And also this in xsp properties

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig="dojo-amd-factory-scan": false
```

But I'm still getting a blank page with no dojo elements displaying

Comment: Use this XSnippet to handle the AMD loader issue: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom control's `beforePageLoad` event gets executed when XPage is loaded already.
When later the tab is activated and with it the table is rendered the variable `viewjson` is gone.

One approach would be to put Java object into a composite data variable `compositeData.viewjson` in beforePageLoad and use it in table later. But, you would calculate *all* views for every tab before rendering page. In addition, this class is not serializable and couldn't be stored in composite data variable. You could make the class serializable though.

The better approach is to instantiate Java bean in table - without a beforePageLoad event:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <table
        id="#{javascript:
            var viewjson = new org.openntf.rest.DynamicView(compositeData.viewName);
            return viewjson.getId();
        }">
        <thead>
            <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" disableOutputTag="true"
                var="col" value="#{javascript: viewjson.getCols()}">
                <th>
                    <xp:text escape="true" disableTheme="true" value="#{col}">
                    </xp:text>
                </th>
            </xp:repeat>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</xp:view>
```

I tested the custom control above (ccView with property viewName) with this XPage

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:br />
    <xp:panel id="tabs">
        <xe:djTabContainer id="tabContainer"
            selectedTab="djTabPane1" defaultTabContent="one">
            <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPaneView" title="one" closable="false"
                partialRefresh="true">
                tab rendered first
            </xe:djTabPane>
            <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane2" title="two" closable="false"
                partialRefresh="true">
                <xc:ccView viewName="ByCity" />
            </xe:djTabPane>
            <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane3" title="three" closable="false"
                partialRefresh="true">
                <xc:ccView viewName="ByName" />
            </xe:djTabPane>
        </xe:djTabContainer>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Views in tabs "two" or "three" get loaded per REST services when user clicks the respective tab.

Comment: Hi Knut, thanks for this, I did actually try the second approach before I posted the question on Stack but it didn't seem to work. I even set a viewScope variable with viewjson.getID() to make sure it was returning something correctly, which it was, but I still got the error....... I'll give it a go again a bit later this morning, it may be possible that I left some legacy bits in my code somewhere.... I'll feedback again a bit later, cheers

Comment: Okay, this works with one instance of my custom control on one tab, however, if I have one cusotm control on one tab, then another custom control on another tab, pointing to different views, I get the following error: DataTables warning: table id=UKDE-AF6CY3 - Requested unknown parameter '3' for row 0. This message pops up twice.... Could it be creating the same ID for both instances of the table within the custom controls?

Comment: Also, going with the bean approach does not work.... Error is com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Not serializable: class org.openntf.rest.DynamicView (org.openntf.rest.DynamicView@2e292e29) Also, FYI, the second option does not work, I get ajax error, however if I leave the beforePageLoad in, its works, but then give me the error mentioned above....

Comment: Hi Chris, couldn't look into it today. I'll take time for it next days.

Comment: No worries Knut, I appreciate you taking the time to help as always! Have a great weekend :-)

Comment: I created an example and it works fine for me. I put both design elements into Oliver's datatables.ntf example database. Hope it works for you too :)

Comment: Hi Knut, do you mean you have included them in a downloadable database somewhere, as if so I'd like to take a look as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.....

Comment: Chris, I meant the datatables_150419.ntf here: https://github.com/zeromancer1972/DataTables

Comment: Hi Knut apologies for the delay, I noticed you updated the code in the example to use the dojo tabs..... I've built an identical page, but nothing seems to render? The page source in firebug is built correctly, but no tabs are shown, just a blank content area..... Any idea's? Thanks again

Comment: No, I put it into my own database

Comment: Why don't you put it into Oliver's database and if it works then go from there?

Comment: Okay, I will try that, however I'm just a bit curios why using the standard dojo layout from the designer palette doesn't actually display the tabs when viewed in the browser

Comment: Maybe you have an AMD loading conflict between Dojo and jQuery? Does browser console show any issues?

Comment: Hi Knut, I've edited my question to show a few things I tried which I believe to help with the AMD loading conflict, but no difference. Thanks

Comment: Use this snippet: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together

Comment: Hi Knut - I've not been able to work on any xpages development for the past month due to other priorities. I'm hoping to be able to commit some time to it again from next week so will keep you in the loop. Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your update. Often priorities change when the end of the year comes closer. Good luck with your current projects.

Comment: Hi Knut, I'm going to accept your answer, as you had it working, and I'm sure if I followed your post I would get it working also, however I have just noticed a limitation with datatables which means it doesn't support categorisation, which means it's not going to be a viable solution for us.... I'm not sure if you are aware of any other options to dynamically create a view on the fly? I have developed a quick dynamicView custom control where I simply pass in a viewName as a custom property but there are limitations.... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe the main problem is that for the XPages core controls a non active tab is not actually rendered to the browser until it becomes active. So what you called in the beforePageLoad() was looking for content that didn't exist at the time.
There's probably a CSJS thing that could re-init the data tables.  Another option is to not use the tab core control but use the dojo version from the ext. library.  I'm pretty sure that the dojo version renders all content and just uses CSS to hide non active tabs.

Comment: Cheers David, I had a feeling it was something to do with the tabs not rendering things until active.... I'm not sure I want to go the dojo route, as one scenario could be any number of tabs, each containing its own view, and if everything is rendered together the load time will then become an issue